# Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text, decode

I have strings like

```
var str = 'One &amp; two &amp; three';
```

rendered into HTML by the web server. I need to transform those strings into

```
'One & two & three'
```

Currently, that's what I am doing (with help of jQuery):

```
$(document.createElement('div')).html('{{ driver.person.name }}').text()
```

However I have an unsettling feeling that I am doing it wrong.
I have tried

```
unescape("&amp;")
```

but it doesn't seem to work, neither do decodeURI/decodeURIComponent.

Are there any other, more native and elegant ways of doing so?