# Replace &amp; to &

Tags: javascript

Due to some Javascript actions to vars I got `&amp;` instead of `&` in my var:
So I tried this:

```
  url_summer = 'http://192.168.0.20/menulb.php?w=chapter&if=If_menulb&p=' + page ;
  url_summer = url_summer.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
  alert(url_summer) ;
```

And the alert gives me:

```
http://192.168.0.20/menulb.php?w=chapter&amp;if=If_menulb&amp;p=521
```

This is strange, the function replace doesn't want to change `&amp;` to `&`. 
If I do the same to change `&amp;` to `+` it works!

```
url_summer = url_summer.replace(/&amp;/g, '+');
```

How cant I change `&amp;` to `&` ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `&amp;` was the only HTML entity that slipped into your URL and all instances of `&` got encoded? Not being in your shoes, it seems easier to just fix the previous manipulation functions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode &amp; back to & in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Decode it like this:

```
var str = "http://192.168.0.20/menulb.php?w=chapter&amp;if=If_menulb&amp;p=521";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Found a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Answer (score 9):

```
url_summer = url_summer.replaceAll('&amp;', '&');
```

Comment: too greedy, this will also replace `foo-amp;`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that answer already. I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```html
var url="http://192.168.0.20/menulb.phpw=chapter&amp;if=If_menulb&amp;p=521"
var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = url;
var decoded = elem.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tt=$('#title').val();
var title=tt.replace(/\&/g,'').replace(/\&amp;/g,'');  
$('#new_title').html(title)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="title" class="text txt100 valid" type="text" id="title" value="Remove and symbol Definition & How it is done" size="100" maxlength="200">

<p id="new_title"></p>
```