# handle &amp; in data during data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a name field which is bound to a textbox. Everything is working fine.
Now when someone enters a unicode character it gets converted to html element.
On page reload the name in input box shows html element. this should not be the case!
how do you fix this?

```
<input placeholder='Name' type="text" ng-model="form.firstName" ng-required="true" />

name = health &amp; wealth
textbox = health &amp; wealth
required in textbox = health & wealth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for format it.

```
<input placeholder='Name' type="text" ng-model="form.firstName | html" ng-required="true" />
```

Add this filter:

```
angular.module("formatFilters", []).filter('html', function() {
    function(input) {
        return input.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    };
});
```

At last,don't forget add this filter in to module.

```
angular.module("app", ['formatFilters'])
```

Comment: i did something like this on data load & before doing anything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript thank you for the answer though.