# replace &amp to & , <lt to < and >gt to gt in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace `&amp` to `&` using javascript. Here is the sample code of mine.EmployeeCode
could contain &. The EmployeeCode is selected from Datagrid and its showed in "txtEmployeeCode" textbox. But if the  EmployeeCode contains any `&` then it shows `&amp` into the textbox. How could `&amp` be removed from EmployeeCode? can anyone help...

```
function closewin(EmployeeCode) {
     opener.document.Form1.txtEmployeeCode.value = EmployeeCode;
     this.close();
}
```

Comment: Use the 'replace' function of JavaScript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With this:

```
function unEntity(str){
   return str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
}

function closewin(EmployeeCode) {
     opener.document.Form1.txtEmployeeCode.value = unEntity(EmployeeCode);
     this.close();
}
```

**OPTIONAL** If you are using jQuery, this will decode any html entity (not only `&amp;` `&lt;` and `&gt;`):

```
function unEntity(str){
   return $("<textarea></textarea>").html(str).text();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: He asked for it. Look at the question title

Comment: I stand corrected. I should really read questions more carefully

Comment: Regex?! Could you please make it more inefficient? Perhaps jQuery can help.

Comment: @bjb568 Microoptimization is evil, regex is perfect for this problem

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i don't know why this is not woring

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps you could explore and implode it a couple times just to make sure you have maximum inefficiency.

Comment: I did explain. It's slow. Just use a string, not regex.

Comment: @bjb568 No, regex wouldn't exist if they were *always* 'slow'. Have you read about microoptimization or premature optimization? Go and do it :)

Comment: Stop lecturing me. Just change it to a string. It's more efficient, easier to read, and doesn't misuse regex. No, regex is for convenience only.

Comment: I won't, that would be **microoptimization**. An EmployeeCode won't be a huge string so it's stupid optimizing it to save a couple milliseconds.

Comment: sorry i had made mistakes. Now it works.Thanks again for your answer @Edgar Villegas Alvarado

Comment: @rafat Welcome. Very glad it helped you :) Cheers

Comment: can you tell me from where i can get very basic knowledge of JQuery? @EdgarVillegasAlvarado

Comment: Here you have a link: http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/jquery-succinctly/?search_index=1
However, the best book I read about jQuery was "JQuery in Action" by Manning. Definitely recommended!

Comment: Not just micro-optimization. It promotes the appropriate use of regex.

Comment: You should replace `&amp;` *last*! Otherwise the ampersand could be double-replaced, e.g. `unEntity("&amp;gt;")` will give `">"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "&amp;";
var newstring = str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
```

For more information, see [MDN's documentation about the String `replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: 1. Regex is a powerful tool 2. It's the only way to make it replace all instances of &amp, instead of just the first one

Comment: Wha? str.replace('&amp;', "&");

Comment: @bjb568 Oh, you criticize without knowing a bit. What you suggest would only replace the first coincidence. With `str = "A&amp;B&amp;C"` your code fails. Please learn before criticizing

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) "The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match." Nothing about the first one.

Comment: @bjb568  oh kid, read well the docs. Or better open your console and eval this: `"A&amp;B&amp;C".replace('&amp;', "&");` It doesn't return `A&B&C` as it should.

Comment: Gah. I they could do a better job of explaining what "some or all" means. Anyway… str.split('&amp').join('&')

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to replace all of those html entities, you can cheat with this:

```
var div = document.createElement('textarea');
div.innerHTML = "bla&amp;bla"
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

your converted value is now in `decoded`

see [Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

A regex-abuse-free method:

```
 function closewin(EmployeeCode) {
      opener.document.Form1.txtEmployeeCode.value = EmployeeCode.split('&amp').join('&');
      this.close();
 }
```

Comment: You'll do it again for &lt and &gt. And dont forget that optional ; behind the entities.