# Binding HTML attribute in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have this code:

```
<span data-icon="{{table.addIcon || '&#xe603;'}}"></span>
```

That span creates an icon like this:

[image: Plus icon]

However, I want to give the developer using this directive, the possibility to define a new icon. It is working, however, the problem I have is that, supposing I have this:

```
$scope.table.addIcon = "&#xe070;"
```

Instead of creating the element

```
<span data-icon="&#xe070;"></span>
```

it will create it

```
<span data-icon="&amp;#xe070;"></span>
```

Which will fail to add the icon, so instead of seeing this:

[image: What I should have...]

What I have is this:

[image: What I do have :(]

Is there a way to avoid angular to convert the `&` into `&amp;`?

**Adding solution**

Thanks to miensol the solution is this:

```
.directive("changeIcon", function() {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, $ele, $attrs) {
            log($attrs);
            var originalIcon;
            $scope.decodedIcon = $attrs.icon;
            do {
                originalIcon = $scope.decodedIcon;
                d.innerHTML = originalIcon;
                $scope.decodedIcon = d.firstChild.nodeValue;
            } while (originalIcon != $scope.decodedIcon);
            $attrs.$set('data-icon', $scope.decodedIcon);
        }
    }
})
```

And it is used like this:

```
<span change-icon icon="{{table.addIcon || '&#xe603;'}}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhaft7f5/) to try out the problem you described but I probably am missing something.

I suspect you're seeing `&amp;` instead of `&` because view is **html encoded on server**.

Either way it's fairly easy to [decode html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript) in javascript. Consider following example:

```
m.directive('icon', function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    return {
        scope: {
            icon:'='
        },
        link: function($scope,$element,$attrs){            
            var originalIcon;
            $scope.decodedIcon = $scope.icon;
            do {
                originalIcon = $scope.decodedIcon;
                div.innerHTML = originalIcon;
                $scope.decodedIcon = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
            } while (originalIcon != $scope.decodedIcon); 
            console.log('data-icon', $scope.decodedIcon);
            $attrs.$set('data-icon', $scope.decodedIcon);
        }
    };
});
```

You can play around with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhaft7f5/2/) hope it helps solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. Actually, if you inspect the first jsfiddle, you will see it is encoded, but the second one does exactly what I need. I'll try it. Thanks!