# HTML Code &amp; not change with replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have put .replace in my code like this :

```
f.hid_LtrContent.value = f.hid_LtrContent.value.replace(/\r\n/g,'[X]').replace(/\t/g,'[Y]').replace(/\&amp;/g, '&');
```

But the value still become "&amp";

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of 1. [Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)   2. [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file-encoding (should be UTF-8).

And you don't have to escape &.

https://jsfiddle.net/00u1u0hn/

```
<script>
var test = 'test&amp;test'.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
document.write(test);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, what's the meaning of "you don't have to escape & ?

Comment: You don't have to write \& in your regex. just &.
If it was the correct answer, please mark it as solution.