# Web text is not displaying properly with ampersand (&) character & amp;

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of names in JavaScript, eg `name = "John&martin"` but in the display in my interface it looks like `John&amp;martin`, with *ampersand* character printed as `&amp;` not as `&`.

I worked with the UTF-8 or even with the ASCII code, but I find no result. How to print `&` character as `&` not as `&amp;`?

Comment: Can you post more context?

Comment: How does your value move from being a Javascript variable to being displayed "in your interface"? It's all about the details between here and there, and we're seeing none of it...

Answer (score -1):

This is a shot in the dark without more context, but have you tried changing the name from:

```
name = "John&martin"
```

to:

```
name = "John\&martin"
```

?

Comment: the problem is reproduced even i would like to display &

Comment: Either post more context or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript