# decodeURIComponent not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
var msg = "Research &amp; Analysis",
    decoder = decodeURIComponent(msg);

console.log(msg);
console.log(decoder);
```

Can someone please help me understand why the `decodeURIComponent(msg);` is not actually decoding the `&amp;` in the string?

I am expecting it to return something like `Research & Analysis` instead of `Research &amp; Analysis`

Comment: What do you expect `decodeURIComponent` to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent` decodes, well, *URI components*, meaning [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) strings. `&amp;` is an HTML entity, not URL-encoding. `decodeURIComponent` has nothing to do with HTML encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to refer you to the documentation of the encode and decode function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

As you can probably understand now, encoding and decoding of an uri has nothing to do with & but is something different.

For the real answer I'd like to refer you to another question + answer here:
[Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)