# Placeholder text set by javascript not decoding HTML encoded special characters

Tags: javascript, html

When setting placeholder text via javascript, special characters are not displaying properly.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "&#201;v&#233;nement";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="&#201;v&#233;nement">

<p>Click the button to change the placeholder text of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Output is: "&#201;v&#233;nement"

Expected output: "Événement"

Looking for a javascript solution where I can convert any text containing any encoded character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Comment: working well on firefox

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "Événement";`?

Comment: @Calaris Don't mix string escape in HTML and string escape in JS.

Comment: @Walk I'd assume the HTML file he's serving is not encoded in UTF8.

Comment: Strings are delivered this way from a back end service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to convert is to create an element, set your HTML entity as innerHTML and get textContent, something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let a = document.createElement('span');
  a.innerHTML = '&#201;v&#233;nement from JS';
  document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = a.textContent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="&#201;v&#233;nement">

<p>Click the button to change the placeholder text of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

In HTML, special characters are encoded with `&#XXX` (Like `&#201`).

In Javascript, special characters are encoded with `\uXXXX` (Like `\u00C9`)

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters for the list of escape code.

In your case, it would be

`document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "\u00C9v\u00E8nement";`

Comment: I don't control the string, I'm looking for a way to convert what I'm given.

Comment: In my case I could control the string, but not the method used to display it as a placeholder, so this was the solution.