# &amp; to & in base64 + Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5, base64

I've got a new problem within my project. I want to create a pdf file via pdfmake. I was following [this tutorial](http://frankzyj2010.blogspot.de/2016/06/how-to-use-pdfmake-to-generate-pdf.html) and everything works fine, except the "transformation" of the '&' sign. In my 'var docDefinition' I am getting content from mysql database. There are some enterprise names with '&'-sign in it. If I call the enterprise name within php, the '&'-sign is shown correctly. But within the javascript and through convert to base64, only 'ampersand' is shown in the generated pdf.
Other signs like 'ö', 'ä' etc. are shown correctly. 
Any ideas?

### Update

Here is a snippet of my code 'generatePDF.blade.php':

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  // Create the PDF
    var docDefinition = {
        pageSize: 'A4',
        pageOrientation: 'portrait',
        ...
        content: [
          { text: 'Ausführende Firma: '},
          '{{ $report->user->enterprise->enterprise_name }}',
          ...
        ],
      };
```

And then the stuff from the tutorial:
    //save the pdf into base64 strings
        var pdfstr;
        try {
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function (result) {
        pdfstr = result;
        console.log('Result: ' + pdfstr);

```
    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(pdfstr);
    console.log('Array: ' + pdfAsArray);

    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function getPdf(pdf) {
        console.log('pdf var: ' + pdf.getPage(1));
      //
      // Fetch the first page
      //
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPdfPage(page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        //
        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        //
        var canvas = $("#pdfviewer").get(0);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Check device pixel ratio and then if the browser is doubleing them
                    console.log('Pixelratio is', window.devicePixelRatio);
                    console.log('The browser is doubleing the pixels:', context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio);

                    var factor = 1;

                    if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 && context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio < 2 || context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio == undefined) {
                        factor = 2;
                    }

        //canvas.height = viewport.height*factor;
        //canvas.width = viewport.width*factor;

        canvas.setAttribute('width', viewport.width*factor);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', viewport.height*factor);
        // context.scale(factor, factor);
        context.transform(devicePixelRatio,0,0,devicePixelRatio,0,0);

        //
        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        //
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport,
        };


        page.render(renderContext);
        // $('#containerPDFViewer').modal({ backdrop: 'static' }); //disable backdrop so user need to make choice
      });
    });
    });
    }
    catch (e) {
    throw e;
    }

    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
      array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      // array[i] = raw.codePointAt(i);
    }

    return array;
    }
```

### Update 2

I figured out, that my problem has noting to do with the javascript part but with the laravel framework I am working with. I am sorry for not telling you, I just forgot to. 
So when I am getting my data from mySQL in my blade view (both UTF-8), everything is fine. But if I do the same not within the pure blade but into javascript my error occurs. So I checked via dd($myvar->value); and so I can see, that the '$'-sign is not converted but the "ampersand ($amp;)". How can I solve that blade prob?

Comment: you can try following link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I added the codesnippet for my problem.

Comment: Thanks @RahulLekurwale, I've seen that post already. Didn't helped me =(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I found an answer for my problem:
some tables in DB were in collation of `utf8_general_ci`, but in laravel /app/config/database.php there is `'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`. So the solution is to change the tables into that collation and then call the values from DB in blade via `{!! $myvar->field !!}` and woooosh, everything works as it should!