# HTML special character (& symbol) not rendering in React component

Tags: reactjs

Consider this react code:

```
subTopicOptions = curSubTopics.map((topic) => {
    return (
        <option value={topic.id}>{topic.name}</option>
    )
});
```

The `topic.name` output `Environment &amp; Forest` value from rest API to display.

How can I display `Environment & Forest` in the select field?

Comment: React escapes the topic name in order to protect you from XSS attacks. The escaped value should display correctly on the actual page, the change is made automatically to make the distinction that you want to display an "&" character and not used for something else.

Comment: Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww7zq93j5k) of a way to do it using `DOMParser`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the browser's native parser as described in the top answer to [Decode & back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript#answers).

Using the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) api, you can do the following:

```js
const strToDecode = 'Environment &amp; Forest';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const decodedString = parser.parseFromString(`<!doctype html><body>${strToDecode}`, 'text/html').body.textContent;
console.log(decodedString);
```

What you're doing there is using the `DOMParser` to create a HTMLDocument by appending our string to decode to the end of `'<!doctype html><body>'`. We can then access the decoded value of our string in the `textContent` of the body of that newly created HTMLDocument.

Comment: All these codes to display an ampersand? What is React doing?

Comment: Seriously!!! I wanted to display right arrow. I just did `<a href="#" className="btn-text">Learn more &rarr;</a>`. **&rarr;**

Comment: https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html
use

```

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: topic.name}} />

```

Answer (score 6):

If creating the topic is under your control, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
subTopicOptions = curSubTopics.map((topic) => {
    return (
        <option value={topic.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: topic.name }} />
    )
});
```

You shoukd be aware that use of the innerHTML can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack, so use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getDecodedString = (str) => {
    const txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.innerHTML = str;
    return txt.value;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering a question, please explain how the code you provided answers the question. When answering an old question with other answers, it is a good practice to explain why yours is different from or improves on the others.