# Angular $routeParams with ampersand

Tags: html, angularjs, ampersand, routeparams

When using routeParams to extract parameters in a url like: 

`https://asdfgh.com/#qwer/search?input1=ZXCV&input2=BNM`

by `$routeParams.input1` and `$routeParams.input2` works great, but in some scenarios when posting the URL in a html page the & changes to `&amp;` like:
`https://asdfgh.com/#qwer/search?input1=ZXCV&amp;input2=BNM`

and then `$routeParams.input2` gets `null`.

What is my solution to this?

Comment: Can you share some code in a context where that happens?

Comment: The system that converts the & to `&amp;` in my application URL is not owned by me. So my question is how to extract params for the second URL, so that my application can still cater to customers.

Comment: If you cannot fix or patch  the system that produces those `&amp;` then all you can do is convert them back to `&`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript