# AngularJS: How to replace #39; and amp; with apostrophe and blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got some data received by an RSS news feed and need to display in in HTML for an ionic framework app. There are two problems. I need to replace `&#39;` and `amp;` with `'` (apostrophe) and blank space.

**AngularJS:**

```
        $scope.rssItems = [];
        var callbackI = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<$marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].rss.length; i+=1){
          $webServicesFactory.get($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].rss[i], {Accept: "application/xml"}).then(
            function success(xmlData) {
              console.log("Home News: ", x2js.xml_str2json(xmlData));                 
              if (x2js.xml_str2json(xmlData) == null)
                  $ionicLoading.hide();


              $scope.rssItems = $scope.rssItems.concat(x2js.xml_str2json(xmlData).rss.channel.item);
//              $scope.rssItems = $scope.rssItems.replace("amp;",""); 

              callbackI+=1;
              if(callbackI == $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].rss.length){
                //console.info($scope.rssItems);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              }
            },
            function error(error) {
              $ionicLoading.hide();
            }
          );
```

and html

```
    <div class="list">
      <h5 class="item item-positive item-divider" align="justify">Today's Headlines</h5>
      <span ng-if="rssItems.length==0">No news available.</span>
      <div class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-bind-html="rssItems(item)" ng-repeat="item in rssItems | orderBy: -dateOrder" ng-click="openNews(item.link)">
        <img ng-src="{{item.enclosure._url || item.enclosure[0]._url || item.content._url || item.thumbnail._url || 'img/icon.png'}}">
        <h2>{{item.title.replace("amp;","") | htmlToPlaintext}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.pubDate | shortDate}}
        <p>{{item.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
      </div>
```

1. `<h2>{{item.title.replace("amp;","") | htmlToPlaintext}}</h2>` able to replace correctly but `<h2>{{item.title.replace("&#39;","'") | htmlToPlaintext}}</h2>` unable to replace with aprotrophe.
2. I need to replace both at once.

Comment: Any feedback lotteryman?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom filter and you will be fine:

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02xrLctb/)**

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{ name  | replaceMe }}!
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'My &#39;sweetamp; &#39;sweetamp;';
});

myApp.filter('replaceMe', function () {
  return function (data) {
   return data.replace(new RegExp('amp;', 'g'), "")
              .replace(new RegExp('&#39;', 'g'), "'")
  }
})
```

Comment: sorry for late feedback. It is working partially. It replace only the first '&#39;` but not all. Also, I am calling like 30 news rss at one time, so , I need to replace all if that happened

Comment: How about using `return data.replace(/&#39;/g, "'").replace(/amp;/g, "")`? is it the same?

Comment: @lotteryman yea its the same. But I recommend to create a RegEx by using "RegExp()" function.