# Avoid amp; in URL through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating table using for loop and in each loop making the text as url as below:

```
txt_2 += "<td> <a href=\"" + urlString + "/\">" + "Sample" + "</a></td>";
```

On clicking the original URL it downloads one file from AWS but when I click on this text 'Sample' on the page, this URL is having amp; where attributes are concatenated at & character, due to which on click the 'Sample' text it is giving an error and not downloading the file

> From page:
>   `https://test.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Sample?AWSAccessKeyId=XYZ&amp;Expires=1534955149&amp;Signature=ababa`
>
> Original:
>   `https://test.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Sample?AWSAccessKeyId=XYZ&Expires=1534955149&Signature=ababa`

I used below code to do the job in code(home.html) but when inspecting the element on the browser it shows me amp; again.

```
var urlString = url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
```

Can i avoid URL to have amp; from the page?

Comment: Well yes, replace `&amp;` with `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the answer here:

[Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)

This is a robust solution as it will tackle any problem with HTML entities.