# Rendering HTML in Kendo Template

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

I'm passing an HTML string as a value into a Kendo Template for the Scheduler groupHeaderTemplate and it's just displaying as normal text rather than rendering the HTML

Demo here...

https://dojo.telerik.com/ELOjalex

Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is displaying as text is not your group header, but this entry in the dataSource: `text: '<span style="color: red;">Alex</span>'`

Comment: Hi, yes I want to be able to pass a value from the dataSource into the group header and it render the HTML correctly

Comment: You need a groupHeaderTemplate in order to achieve this. Check the example https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/group#groupHeaderTemplate

Comment: Hi Carlos, if you check the Dojo link you'll see I've tried that using inline and external templates and neither has worked. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest not to put HTML into your datasource. I am sure you can find a better solution to submit additional information (like the color).

You can get the desired result if you make an additional call from your template and parse the string from the datasource:

```js
<script id="groupHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <strong style="color: #=color#">#=doMagic(text)#</strong>
</script>

<script>
function doMagic(s) {
  return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(s, 'text/html').body.textContent;
}
</script>
```

(Kudos to [Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript))

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure there is another way as I only have access to predetermined properties within the GroupHeaderTemplate (text).