# Display Specials characters from MYSQL in modal form Jquery?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a code jquery who display a value from mysql data to a modal window form.

```
editRow: function(row){
var values = row.val();
...
$editor.find('#mail_username').val(values.mail_username);
...
$modal.data('row', row);
$modal.modal('show');
},
```

Example : The correct value in mysql is "toto&titi"

But in my modal window : "toto`&amp;`titi"

How to correctly display specials characters in my modal form ?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mail_username" name="mail_username" required>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try doing like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode your text by

```
let mail_username = "toto&amp;titi";
let decode = $("<div/>").html(mail_username).text();
```

```js
let mail_username = "toto&amp;titi";
let decode = $("<div/>").html(mail_username).text();
$('#mail_username').val(decode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='mail_username' />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hien !!!

My good syntax:

$editor.find('#mail_username').val($("<div/>").html(values.mail_username).text());

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Hien !!!

I post below my good syntax:

```
$editor.find('#mail_username').val($("<div/>").html(values.mail_username).text());
```